# P2OS Debian Release: Travis Build Failing

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Still having issues with this whole packaging for release thing...

```
rosdistro: DEBUG: Load package.xml file from url "https://raw.github.com/ros-gbp/p2os-release/release/groovy/p2os_driver1.0.0/package.xml"
rosdistro: DEBUG: - failed (HTTP Error 404: Not Found), trying "https://raw.github.com/ros-gbp/p2os-release/release/groovy/p2os_driver1.0.0/package.xml"
rosdistro: DEBUG: Could not shallow clone repository "https://github.com/ros-gbp/p2os-release.git"
rosdistro: DEBUG: Load package.xml file from url "https://raw.github.com/ros-gbp/p2os-release/release/groovy/p2os_launch1.0.0/package.xml"
rosdistro: DEBUG: - failed (HTTP Error 404: Not Found), trying "https://raw.github.com/ros-gbp/p2os-release/release/groovy/p2os_launch1.0.0/package.xml"
rosdistro: DEBUG: Could not shallow clone repository "https://github.com/ros-gbp/p2os-release.git"
rosdistro: DEBUG: Load package.xml file from url "https://raw.github.com/ros-gbp/p2os-release/release/groovy/p2os_teleop1.0.0/package.xml"
rosdistro: DEBUG: - failed (HTTP Error 404: Not Found), trying "https://raw.github.com/ros-gbp/p2os-release/release/groovy/p2os_teleop1.0.0/package.xml"
rosdistro: DEBUG: Could not shallow clone repository "https://github.com/ros-gbp/p2os-release.git"
rosdistro: DEBUG: Load package.xml file from url "https://raw.github.com/ros-gbp/p2os-release/release/groovy/p2os_urdf1.0.0/package.xml"
rosdistro: DEBUG: - failed (HTTP Error 404: Not Found), trying "https://raw.github.com/ros-gbp/p2os-release/release/groovy/p2os_urdf1.0.0/package.xml"
rosdistro: DEBUG: Could not shallow clone repository "https://github.com/ros-gbp/p2os-release.git"
```

As is plainly seen, the p2os-release repository does not exist on ros-gdp... How do I go about packaging it with my repository? Do I need to contact someone to get it added to ros-gdp?

---

This is the change I am trying to merge with the groovy release.yaml:

```
  p2os:
    packages:
      p2os_driver:
      p2os_launch:
      p2os_teleop:
      p2os_urdf:   
    tags:
      release: release/groovy/{package}{upstream_version}
    url: https://github.com/ros-gbp/p2os-release.git
    version: 1.0.0
```

Is this correct?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65520/p2os-debian-release:-travis-build-failing/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2013-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had to set up a separate repository for the code. It wasn't going to work on someone else's repository. Stupid mistake I guess...

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2013-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0